# Values of keyword,source ,medium fields in google analytics is getting as undefined

Tags: seo, google-analytics

I am using google analytics in my site for getting searched keyword , source and medium. I got the values for these. I am using php and js for coding. But my problem is , in some cases keyword , source and medium is showing as undefined . What may be the reason for this?

Can any one help me please?

Comment: Please provide a code with which you are sending keyword, source and medium to Google Analytics and screenshot of report you are looking at. This way me or anyone else from the community will be able to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

In October 2011 Google changed their terms to enhance privacy of users.

If a user is logged into a Google account then no referrers are sent (by the analytics script on your site) to *your* Google Analytics account (Google still has that info though) this includes keywords, etc.

Long story short, user privacy => SSL => less juicy analytics data for any of your visitors who are logged into a Google account.

Workarounds: 
[Unlock Keyword Not Provided - by Kissmetrics.com](https://blog.kissmetrics.com/unlock-keyword-not-provided/)